# How do headers work in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, header, llvm

Beyond allowing one file to use another file's attributes, what actually happens behind the scenes? Does it just provide the location to access to that file when its contents are later needed, or does it load the implementation's data into memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short;

The header file defines the API for a module. It's a contract listing which methods a third party can call. The module can be considered a black box to third parties.

The implementation implements the module. It is the inside of the black box. As a developer of a module you have to write this, but as a user of a third party module you shouldn't need to know anything about the implementation. The header should contain all the information you need.

Some parts of a header file could be auto generated - the method declarations. This would require you to annotate the implementation as there are likely to be private methods in the implementation which don't form part of the API and don't belong in the header.

Header files sometimes have other information in them; type definitions, constant definitions etc. These belong in the header file, and not in the implementation.
The main reason for a header is to be able to #include it in some other file, so you can use the functions in one file from that other file. The header includes (only) enough to be able to use the functions, not the functions themselves, so (we hope) compiling it is considerably faster.

Maintaining the two separately most results from nobody ever having written an editor that automates the process very well. There's not really a lot of reason they couldn't do so, and a few have even tried to -- but the editors that have done so have never done very well in the market, and the more mainstream editors haven't adopted it.

Well i will try:
Header files are only needed in the preprocessing phase. Once the preprocessor is done with them the compiler never even sees them. Obviously, the target system doesn't need them either for execution (the same way .c files aren't needed).

Instead libraries are executed during the linking phase.If a program is dynamically linked and the target environment doesn't have the necessary libraries, in the right places, with the right versions it won't run.
In C nothing like that is needed since once you compile it you get native code. The header files are copy pasted when u #include it . It is very different from the byte-code you get from java. There's no need for an interpreter(like the JVM): you just feed it your binary stuff to the CPU and it does its thing.

Comment: Was hoping for a compiler-level explanation, but this is a wonderful overview of headers.

Comment: i edit some more lines and you have this link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor
i am sorry that i don't have any further depth.

Comment: The extra bit is enlightening. I think my curiosity is leading me to linking.